# view application and Console application in objective C

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to Objective C..I have created some applications in view based application..My project is to develop a protocol to retreive records.I'm writing that coding in console application..If the user clicks on the ok button the data has to be retrieved from the other end... Have created the buttons and TextView to display the status in the view based application and rest of the format of sending data as packets i'm trying to do it in console based application.Is there any possiblility of including the view based application as well as the console based application together in a single project.If i add up the .m and .h files from the console application to the view based application its showing me some error on the "cocoa/cocoa.h No such file or directory".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have added the **Cocoa** framework to your console project. The framework is at `/System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Headers/` but you should just have to go to add frameworks and search for Cocoa.